# In the coslice category, why are the morphisms from the terminal category element inclusions?

Tags: category-theory

[Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Coslice_category) definition of the coslice category uses the symbols $i_B$ for the objects $(B,i_B)\in(A\downarrow\mathcal C)$. Similarly, the definition of the slice category uses the symbol $\pi_B$.

I've seen the same symbols in other texts, and AFAIK the reason for these symbols is that $i_B$ are inclusions and $\pi_B$ are projections.

Is that true? If yes, why are they inclusions/projections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general, they are not inclusions or projections. I suppose that the reason the suggestive notation is used is due to universal arrows and universal properties. For example, if 
$$F:R\text{-Mod}\to \text{Set}$$
is the forgetful functor, then a universal arrow from a set $A$ to $F$ is a pair $(j,F(A))$, where $j:A\to F(A)$ is an injective set function and $F(A)$ is (isomorphic to) the free module on $A$. That is, the pair $(j,F(A))$ is a universal arrow from $A$ to $F$ iff it is an initial object in the category $(A\downarrow R\text{-Mod})$.